# Check if it is specific day in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a app that checks if it is Friday, if it is Friday I want it to say Yes and no if it is not Friday, now it says no automatic and when I press on the `FloatingActionButton` it says Yes. How can I make it check and then send No or Yes to the app.
Current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    ));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

String isItFriday = 'No';

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isItFriday = 'Yes';
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 250, 30, 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Is it friday?',
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                '$isItFriday',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your code and your error.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @RobertSandberg Question is now changed with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setState method that is called in your floating action button just change this line:

```
isItFriday = 'Yes';
```

to this line:

```
isItFriday = DateTime.now().weekday == DateTime.friday ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then now you can use the **format** date

```
if( DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now() == 'Friday') print('Its Friday')
```

Or You can do it like this

```
 ( DateTime.now().weekday == 5 ) print('Its Friday')
```

Comment: No need for using an external package for that. Just do: `DateTime.now().weekday == DateTime.friday`.